# Convert Time Zone from a String to a particular Time Zone taking DST into consideration of target Time Zone

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert a date string in format "yyyyMMddHHmmss" to a date string for another Time Zone "America/Sao_Paulo" taking DST into consideration for America/Sao_Paulo ( which start on 16-oct-2016 ).

I am using TimeZone class as

> TimeZone represents a time zone offset, and also figures out daylight
>   savings.

```
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;;

public class TimeZoneConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");     
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
            try

            {   
                String inputdate = "20161016052355";
                Date t = sdf.parse(inputdate);  
                System.out.println(t);
            }
            catch(ParseException e)
            {

            }    
    }
}
```

Output for the above is shown in IST

`Sun Oct 16 12:53:55 IST 2016`

How can i convert the the time string with input "yyyyMMddHHmmss" to a time string in "America/Sao_Paulo" Time Zone with DST in output ?

Comment: I tried, But it's not calculating the DST then.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you very clearly divide your question into two *separate* halves, (1) **input** you are given, and (2) **output** you desire?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
try
{
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
Date time = f.parse("20161015113634");  


DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

System.out.println(formatter.format(time)); 
}
catch (ParseException e){
    
}
```

> Input : 20161015113634 (Time which is not in DST)
>
> > Output: 20161015030634 (Converted time for SaoPaulo)
>
> Input : 20161016113634 (Time in DST)
>
> > Output: 20161016040634 (Converted time for SaoPaulo with DST Offset)

Answer (score 1):

You are simply printing it in a timezone where it is not daylight savings time on that date - printing a `Date` prints it in the JVM's default timezone.

For instance, replacing `System.out.println(t)` with:

```
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zzzz");
out.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(out.format(t));
```

prints:

```
2016/10/16 05:23:55 Brasilia Summer Time
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FyTa8G)

Comment: Then how can i convert it to DST time as "2016/10/16" is DST in Brazil and it is still printing the same time.

Comment: I think that you might be confused by what DST means. That one time zone is DST doesn't mean that you need to describe the time in DST when converting to another time zone.

Comment: But, that is my requirement. I need the Time to be converted into a DST time.

Comment: Then you need to be converting it into a time zone which *is* in DST at that instant. It is *literally* meaningless to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input lacks any offset-from-UTC or time zone info. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`, meaning *any* locality.

```
String input = "20161016052355";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2016-10-16T05:23:55

A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline. To give it real meaning, you must provide the intended time zone (or offset).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Sao_Paulo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-10-16T05:23:55-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

To see the same moment as UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-10-16T07:23:55Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/6XOVRu).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this...

please replace your specific time_zone

string dts = "May 16, 2010 7:20:12 AM CDT";
DateTime dt = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(dts.Replace("CDT", "-05:00"), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);

Comment: My String is specifically in "yyyyMMddHHmmss" format, it's the requirement and i am only given time zone in this format "America/Sao_Paulo".